# How to analyse a non-inferiority trial using GEE in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-estimating-equations, non-inferiority, geepack

I'm trying to analyse a non-inferiority trial in R. Since there are correlated observations and a population averaged interpretation seems fine, I want to use GEE.

To illustrate my problem, I will use the *muscatine* data that is embedded in the *gee* package in R.
The research question can be as follows, I want to investigate if the male participants in the muscatine data have a non-inferior obesity level compared to the females (so equivalent to testing if 'males' is a new, non-inferior drug compared to the standard drug 'females')

The outcome 'obese' and variable 'gender' are both binary, age and occasion are controlled for and continuous (not important tho)

- **The problem at hand:** I know how to perform a GEE in R, but how can I get p-values corresponding to a non-inferiority trial with **non inferiority margin equal to $0.01$**? (So this is equivalent to testing $H_0:β_1 ≤- 0.01$ vs $H_a:β_1 > -0.01$, where $β_1$ is the log-odds ratio of course). I can only find online that GEE tests 2-sided hypotheses with $β_1 = 0$.

I used the following code:

```
library(gee)
data(muscatine)

data2 <- muscatine
data2$obese <- ifelse(muscatine$obese == 'yes', 0, 1)

x <- gee(obese ~ gender + age + occasion, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = "exchangeable", data = data2)
summary(x)
```

This gives me the following output concerning the coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)   1.7846     0.1152   15.49      0.1116    16.00
genderF      -0.1521     0.0620   -2.45      0.0626    -2.43
age          -0.0296     0.0113   -2.63      0.0110    -2.68
occasion     -0.0377     0.0298   -1.27      0.0310    -1.22
```

REMARK: I posted this already on Stack Overflow, but they suggested to move it here and someone indicated my alternative hypothesis is wrong, but I can't find the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypotheses do not match your particular dummy coding.

You have the probability of being obese $\pi$, modelled in the log-odds scale. You want to show that males are no less obese than females, or $\pi_{M}>\pi_F-\Delta$ for some margin $\Delta$. This is your alternative hypothesis which is equivalent to any of:
$$\pi_M-\pi_F>-\Delta$$
$$\pi_M-\pi_F+\Delta>0$$
Your null hypothesis is that $\pi_M\le\pi_F-\Delta$, and your choice of margin seems to be $\Delta=0.01$ in the log-odds scale.

Because `genderM` is the reference level in your model, $\beta_1$ expresses the difference in log-odds between *females and males* ($\pi_F-\pi_M$ in the probability scale), not vice versa. The lower the value of $\beta_1$ the less likely females are to be obese compared to males, which confirms your $H_a$. To be correct you'll either have to swap the dummy coding or flip the signs in your hypotheses, e.g. $H_a:\pi_F-\pi_M<\Delta$ or $H_0:\beta_1\ge0.01$.

There are at least two options for doing your non-inferiority test, I'll use your model as coded and not your hypotheses as you stated them.

The first is to do a one-sided hypothesis test directly, i.e. test $\frac{\hat{\mu_F}-\hat{\mu_M}-\Delta}{s}<0$. Your model has provided $\hat{\mu_F}-\hat{\mu_M}$ as $\beta_1$ and its (GEE-corrected) standard error $s$, so this boils down to a one-sided Z-test with $z=\frac{-0.1521-0.01}{0.0626}$ resulting in $P=0.0048$. You could and probably should make this a t-test if you have the degrees of freedom on this estimate available.

A second option is just a restating of the above test, making use of the relation between a *P*-value and a confidence interval: instead of testing $\beta_1-\Delta$ at a one-sided $\alpha$ you can also reject inferiority if the two-sided $(1-2\alpha)$ confidence interval on $\beta_1$ excludes $\Delta$. In this case that would be the upper limit specifically, or you could also look at the relevant one-sided $(1-\alpha)$ CI. You'll have to keep in mind that in a regulatory context you don't get to double-dip,  $\alpha=0.025$ is the usual one-sided threshold. Calculating the normal-based confidence interval $\beta_1\pm s\times\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ you'll see that its upper limit is below $\Delta$ from common values of $\alpha$ (in fact, all those down to about $0.0048$), matching the above result. Also here I would consider making this t-based if possible.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! You are indeed right that I was sloppy with my dummy coding in R, apologies. I didn't know the solution was that 'simple', the main concern I had was if it is really valid to use a Z-test because the variable z with the correction of delta is maybe not standard normally distributed anymore, but it makes sense this way!

Btw, is your advise to use a t-test instead of Z-test just to capture more uncertainty with the long tails, or is there another reason?

Comment: Yes, using t instead of Z adds correction for sampling variability in the standard error estimate. In hindsight I'm not sure that's a 'thing' in GEE and the conclusions hold down to about 3 df, so I wouldn't worry too much about it, but it's always nice to have.